# flink table api day year month extraction

Tags: java, sql, apache-flink, flink-streaming, flink-sql

How can i extract day hour and time from frilk table api

```
final Table select = transactions
                .window(Tumble.over(lit(1).hour()).on($("transaction_time")).as("log_ts"))
                .groupBy($("transaction_time").year(),$("transaction_time").month(),$("transaction_time").day())
                .select(
                        $("account_id"),
                        $("log_ts").start().as("log_ts"),
                        $("amount").sum().as("amount") );
        return select;
```

i want to group based on each day  . example record

> cast(2020-01-01T00:12, TIMESTAMP(3))

the above group by is something what i was trying but its showing the following error

> org.apache.flink.table.api.ValidationException: Invalid constant for
> year-month interval: transaction_time

Comment: The available temporal functions are listed here: https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/dev/table/functions/systemFunctions.html#temporal-functions

Comment: @DavidAnderson i came across that but was not sure how to execute it right way

Comment: The easiest way to figure that out would probably be to use the Flink SQL client, so that you can interactively try things until you find something that works.

Comment: @DavidAnderson hi how to add AUTO_INCREMENT TO a uid

Comment: @DavidAnderson.  `tEnv.executeSql("CREATE TABLE spend_report (\n" +
                "    main_id BIGINT    ,\n" +
                "    account_id BIGINT,\n" +
                "    log_ts     TIMESTAMP(3),\n" +
                "    amount     BIGINT\n," +
                "    PRIMARY KEY (main_id) NOT ENFORCED   " +`